# PSD to HTML navigation bar slicing concern

Tags: html, psd

In my PSD file I have a nav bar with some light effect in the background. I'm a bit concerned whether should I slice the whole nav bar and then add text or just slice it into smaller pieces? Which would be the best practice? 
 I'm new to this subject so any ideas would be so much appreciated. [image]

Comment: You for sure want to cut the nav bar images in to pieces. Add them to the background of each of the nav bar links with css. It will save you a big head ache later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You for sure want to cut the nav bar images into pieces. Add them to the background of each of the nav bar links with css. It will save you a big headache later.

Here is a good example of a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PbKD/38/)

Css

```
#nav {
    display: block; 
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px; 
    list-style: none outside none; 
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
    max-width: 750px; 
    min-width: 750px; 
    width: 78.2%;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
}

#nav li a{
    color: #fff; 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-light,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1em; 
    height: 100%; 
    padding: 0px 23px 0; 
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    background:#4D4D4D; 
    position: relative;
}

#nav li a span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    display: none
}

#nav li a:hover, #nav .active a {
    background: url("path/to/image.png") no-repeat bottom  center #a4c723;
    color: #4d4d4d;
}

#nav li a:hover span, #nav .active a span {
    display: block;   
}
```

Comment: so you meant I should slice the left and right sides of the navbar? so how to deal with the border at between list items?

Comment: You are going to creat links wtih css and make the backtround of each link a image. then you can adjust the border with css and you will be able to target each link directly

Comment: I saw a tutorial which they just slice the whole navbar and then put text on. What is not good about this practice?

Comment: Well if you want to do the hole navbar you can. But you will have to make sure your dimension are perfect. you have a little more wiggle room and can easily target each link if you split them. If I were you I would do it both ways and see which you like better

Comment: sir thank you for the advice. I'm gonna give each one a try

Answer (score 0):

if you mean gradients, you can use gradient generator http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

As for me, using as few images as possible is best practice. Draw your navbar with css, good luck